# DICCIONARIOS Y LISTAS python

Tags: python, diccionarios

necesito ayuda en lo siguiente:
Supongamos que tengo 2 diccionarios.

```
dic1 = {"Mesa": ["madera", "clavos"], "Ventana": ["vidrio", "madera", "clavos"], "Silla": ["madera","tela","clavos"]}
# Valores del diccionario1 corresponden a 1und.
dic2 = {"madera": 10, "clavos": 5, "tela": 10, "vidrio": 3}
```

si tengo un input para llamar el objeto que quiero hacer que se encuentra en el diccionario1:

```
obj = input() #CREAR mesa, CREAR ventana, CREAR silla
```

Como puedo restar al diccionario2 los elementos que conforman el objeto que ingreso en el input?

ejemplo:

```
obj = "CREAR silla" #el cual corresponde a 1und de madera, 1und de tela y 1und de clavos
```

por lo que el resultado que quiero posterior a ingresar el obj es el siguiente:

```
dic2 = {"madera": 9, "clavos": 4, "tela": 9, "vidrio": 3}
```

Y dentro del proceso obviamente omitir la palabra CREAR.

Agradezco desde ya su ayuda y explicacion del proceso.

Bueno lo que tengo es esto:

```
diccionario_objetos = {}
objetos = []

archivo1 = open("objetos.csv", "r")

for i in archivo1.readlines():
    objetos = i.rstrip("\n").split(",")
    for i in objetos:
        diccionario_objetos[objetos[0]] = objetos[1:]

archivo1.close()

diccionario_materiales = {}
materiales = []

archivo2 = open("materiales.txt","r")

for i in archivo2.readlines():
    materiales = i.rstrip("\n").split(" ")
    for i in materiales:
            diccionario_materiales[materiales[0]] = int(materiales[1])

archivo2.close()
 

print(diccionario_objetos)
print(diccionario_materiales)

obj = input().split(" ") #aca separo el CREAR con el objeto que deseo
obj.pop(0) #borro de la lista obj "CREAR" quedando el objeto que deseo
print(obj)

#aca es donde empieza mi dolor de cabeza

for i in obj:
    for j in diccionario_objetos:
        if i == j:
            print(diccionario_objetos[j])
```

Llego hasta aca con este print que me indica los materiales que utiliza el objeto y desde aca he intentado hacer de todo para poder realizar la resta al diccionario de materiales los elementos que conforman el objeto a crear.

Comment: Podrías agregar el código que lograste hacer hasta ahora por favor? Demuéstranos que eres parte del esfuerzo de responder tu propia pregunta!

Comment: Puedo seleccionar responder a mi propia pregunta para ingresar lo que tengo?

Comment: Hiciste bien en preguntar! Si quieres añadir información en al pregunta, puedes editarla presionando el boton editar que está abajo de la pregunta y las etiquetas! Cualquier duda que tengas con eso dime c:

Comment: ahi pude editar la pregunta, añadi la info que tengo en mi codigo, di el ejemplo anterior para hacerlo mas sencillo, ya que en lo que estoy haciendo tengo que importar archivos

Answer (score 2):

Lo logre.

Realice lo siguiente:

```py
for i in obj:
    for j in diccionario_objetos:
        if i == j:
            for k in diccionario_objetos[j]:
                diccionario_materiales[k] -= 1
```

Con esto pude restar al diccionario de materiales los materiales que utiliza el objeto que quiero "crear".

Agradecere cualquier indicacion para reducir codigo o dejar mas pulcro lo que tengo.

Answer (score 1):

Añadiendo a tú resultado.

Creo que `obj` es una variable, no una lista con lo que no te hace falta recorrerla.

La podrías asignar así:
`obj = input('Crear _ _ _').split()[1].title()`

- Separas las 2 palaras y te quedas con la segunda.
- El espacio en lanco es el valor por defecto en split()
- Con title te aseguras de que el dato empiece por mayúscula

Otra cosa que igual has hecho pero no pones en este código es comprobar si existen los materiales antes de borrarlos de tus materiales.

Puedes crear un diccionario auxiliar en el que vas borrando. Si te falta algo envías mensaje y si acabas teniendo los materiales copias el diccionario aux a diccionario_materiales.

```
sw = True   #   Para controlar si hay materiales suficientes

d_aux = diccionario_materiales.copy()

for mat in diccionario_objetos[obj]:
    if d_aux[mat]:
        d_aux[mat] -= 1
    else:
        sw = False

if sw:
    #   Si tenemos todos los materiales 
    diccionario_materiales = d_aux.copy()
else:
    print('No se pudo crear el objeto')

print(f'Me quedan {diccionario_materiales}')
```

Comment: Lo probare, ya que tal como dices, la idea es que arroje una indicacion si no cuenta con algun material. Gracias.

Comment: Editado para el caso de que no lo encuentre